# Kotlin Lambda expressions

Tags: android, kotlin

The following functions are used in each of the examples

```
fun trickOrTreat(isTrick: Boolean, extraTreat: (Int) -> String): () -> Unit {
  if (isTrick) {
    println(extraTreat(2))
    return trick
  } else {
    println(extraTreat(5))
    return treat
  }
}

val trick = {
  println("No treats!")
}

val treat = {
  println("Have a treat!")
}
```

Example 1

```
fun main(){
      val coins: (Int) -> String = { quantity -> "$quantity quarters" }

      val cupcake: (Int) -> String = { "Have $it cupcake!" }

      val treatFunction = trickOrTreat(false, coins)
      val trickFunction = trickOrTreat(true, cupcake)
}
```

The output for the above code

[image]

Why are the functions getting executed while assigning to the val?

Example 2

```
fun main() {
      val coins: (Int) -> String = { quantity ->
        "$quantity quarters"
      }

      val cupcake: (Int) -> String = {
        "Have $it cupcake!"
      }
      val treatFunction = trickOrTreat(false, coins)
      val trickFunction = trickOrTreat(true, cupcake)
      repeat(4) { i -> 
        treatFunction()
        println("iteration ${i+1}")
      }
}
```

The output for the above code

[image]

Why are the lambdas not getting executed when the treatFunction() called each time in repeat?

Example 3

```
fun main() {
  val coins: (Int) -> String = { quantity ->
    "$quantity quarters"
  }

  val cupcake: (Int) -> String = {
    "Have $it cupcake!"
  }

  val treatFunction = trickOrTreat(false, coins)
  val trickFunction = trickOrTreat(true, cupcake)

  repeat(4) { i -> 
    trickOrTreat(false, coins)
    println("iteration ${i+1}")
  }
}
```

The output for the above code

[image]

How are the lambdas getting executed when the function is called directly?

Comment: What is your expected behavior? It feels you got lost somehow in your own code. `trickOrTreat` calls the passed lambda every time we call it - in either line 3 or 6. Then it returns either `treat` or `trick` function. All your examples works accordingly to the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Example 1

This code:

```kotlin
val treatFunction = trickOrTreat(false, coins)
val trickFunction = trickOrTreat(true, cupcake)
```

Runs the functions and assigns the results to the variables (which is either `trick` or `treat`). When the functions are executed they are outputting the `println` contained within them.

#### Example 2

```kotlin
val treatFunction = trickOrTreat(false, coins)
```

As described above assigns the value of `treat` which is a lambda function.

Then in the loop:

```kotlin
treatFunction()
```

Runs that function giving the output of `println` in the `treat` lambda.

> Why are the lambdas not getting executed when the treatFunction() called each time in repeat?

Because you're only calling the lambda returned from the original function invocation.

#### Example 3

No difference here in the loop, you're executing the function every time with the same result (just ignoring the return value).

Answer (score 1):

Example 1: the `trickOrTreat()` function is invoking whatever function you passed to it in the if and else branches. Notice your code is invoking the passed function by calling `extraTreat(2)` or `extraTreat(5)`.

Example 2: the `coin` or `cupcake` lambdas get invoked when `trickOrTreat()` is called. You aren’t calling them in the loop. Instead, you are directly invoking the `treat` function, which performs only the code within itself. There’s no reason it would somehow reinvoke the `trickOrTreat()` function when it gets invoked.

Example 3: this is a repeat of the first question.